# JavaScript / jQuery - How to stop slideDown from scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll

I just recently started using WP with the Divi theme. However, I quickly ran into the first limitations of the theme and now am trying to sort this out manually.

I tried finding a solution to this problem before (extensively if I may say), but I just can't wrap my head around why my problem persists - mostly as I have absolutely no prior experience with Javascrip/jQuery.

**What I am trying to do:**

Have multiple buttons and on click show different divs. Once a different one is selected by the user, the previous one should be hidden - Currently I only use two buttons for testing.

**What is working:**

Both hiding and showing is working and there is no problem if the buttons are used in the sequence: Click 1. button to show -> click 1. button to hide -> then click 2. button to show etc.

**My problem:**

However, if the first button's div is visible and the second button is clicked, does what it's supposed to do but scrolls to the very end of the page. This is the behavior I am trying to stop.

I haven't understood yet, how I can get the neccessary HTML to make a working JSFiddle, but below is the code, which is implemented by the theme into the body of the page. It is mostly based on some code I found on this site, but I can't seem to find the original post.

I ve tried using scrollTop as well as the current tempScroll, which I saw in yet another post as a method to save the scrolling position and recalling it. However, no matter what I put in, it doesnt seem to change the behavior.

I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction or other help and hope that I posted this correctly.

Cheers

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $('.button_verstecken_click').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if(!targetDiv.is(':visible')){
      $('.button_verstecken').slideUp();
      targetDiv.slideDown('slow',function(){);
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{
      $('.button_verstecken').slideUp();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see how that code would work at all given the syntax error `function(){);` on the `.slideDown()` line. Is the missing `}` just a typo in what you've pasted into the question? (Also, in future please help us to help you by properly indenting your code to make it more readable - I've done it for you in this case.)

Comment: Post your HTML too.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and replies. I've put the things in a Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/oh5r628a) and removed the prevent default function. I am not sure that the problem is obvious here. What I intend to show with each click are two rather large sets of different staff (pictures, etc.) Thus, the problem might only occur, if the content exceeds the screen height.